# Unexpected output from the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my query

```
DECLARE @AvgCharges TABLE (
    AverageTotalCharges MONEY
    ,ModeTotalCharges MONEY
    ,ServiceCode VARCHAR(20)
    ,SampleCount INT
    ,[EstimatedAllowedAmount] MONEY
    ,[Source] INT
    ,[Description] VARCHAR(200)
    )

INSERT INTO @AvgCharges
SELECT ISNULL(cpe.AverageTotalCharges, 0) AverageTotalCharges
    ,cpe.ModeTotalCharges
    ,svc.ServiceCode
    ,cpe.SampleCount
    ,EstimatedAllowedAmount = CASE 
        WHEN cpe.Mode = 1
            THEN AverageBP
        ELSE MaximumAllowedBP
        END
    ,1 [Source]
    ,''
FROM [Services] svc(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN CPTPlanCodeEstimates cpe(NOLOCK) ON svc.ServiceCode = cpe.CPT4Code
WHERE svc.RegistrationID = 1918605
    AND cpe.StandardPatientType = 'O'
    AND cpe.PayorPlanCode = '101M'

SELECT *
FROM @avgcharges  -- here i have 1 record

PRINT @@ROWCOUNT  -- show 1

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @AvgCharges (
        AverageTotalCharges
        ,ServiceCode
        ,[Source]
        )
    SELECT EstimatedCharges
        ,svc.ServiceCode
        ,2 [source]
    FROM [Services] svc(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Estimates e(NOLOCK) ON svc.ServiceCode = e.Code
    WHERE svc.RegistrationID = 1918605
        AND PatientType = 'O'
        AND e.CodeType = (
            CASE 
                WHEN @PatientType = 'I'
                    THEN 'DRG'
                ELSE 'CPT'
                END
            )
    ORDER BY EstimatedCharges DESC
END

SELECT *
FROM @avgcharges   -- here I am getting 2 records in my table, which should be 1 actually.
```

I am getting two rows in my table which should be one actually. I think here `if @@rowcount = 0` condition is not getting satisfied.

Any ideas or alternatives?

Please note I using SQL Server 2005 SP4

Comment: Could your `PRINT @@ROWCOUNT` be actually resetting `@@ROWCOUNT` to 0 because no rows are returned by a print? What does `PRINT @@ROWCOUNT; PRINT @@ROWCOUNT` show?

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187316.aspx) says "Statements such as USE, SET <option>, DEALLOCATE CURSOR, CLOSE CURSOR, BEGIN TRANSACTION or COMMIT TRANSACTION reset the ROWCOUNT value to 0." - So maybe `PRINT` is one of those statements, too.

Comment: Thanks @HannoBinder... print @@RowCount was interefing the statement.

Comment: @AmitRanjan: Every insert/update/select/set/delete statement resets the @@rowcount. So what i would suggest is take the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` into some variable and then use that variable into if condition something like this - `SET @ROWCNT = @@ROWCOUNT; IF @ROWCNT = 0`

Comment: Why are you littering your query with NOLOCK? Is accuracy not important? Do you know you can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows? http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx